# Why doesn't the OnDraw suffice (in MFC, Scribble tutorial)

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm making the Scribble tutorial to learn MFC and there's this code on the MouseMove event:

```
void CScribbleView::OnMouseMove(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
    // Mouse movement is interesting in the Scribble application
    // only if the user is currently drawing a new stroke by
    // dragging the captured mouse.

    if( GetCapture( ) != this )
        return;        // If this window (view) didn't capture the
    // mouse, the user isn't drawing in this window.

    // Add the new point to the current stroke
    m_pStrokeCur->m_pointArray.Add(point);

    CClientDC dc( this );

    // Draw a line from the previous detected point in the mouse
    // drag to the current point.
    CPen* pOldPen =
        dc.SelectObject( GetDocument( )->GetCurrentPen( ) );
           dc.MoveTo( m_ptPrev );
           dc.LineTo( point );
           dc.SelectObject( pOldPen );

    m_ptPrev = point;

    CView::OnMouseMove(nFlags, point);
}
```

And this one on the draw function of the stroke (which is called by the OnDraw of the view):

```
BOOL CStroke::DrawStroke( CDC* pDC )
{
    CPen penStroke;
    if( !penStroke.CreatePen(PS_SOLID, m_nPenWidth, RGB(0,0,0)))
        return FALSE;
    CPen* pOldPen = pDC->SelectObject( &penStroke );
    pDC->MoveTo( m_pointArray[0] );
    for( int i=1; i < m_pointArray.GetSize(); i++ )
    {
        pDC->LineTo( m_pointArray[i] );
    }
    pDC->SelectObject( pOldPen );
    return TRUE;
}
```

I've checked this function is being called on every frame update. However, if I take away the drawing on the mouse move event, it won't happen anything, even though I'm registering all the strokes and the draw stroke function is being called. Only if I make changes to the window (like maximizing) will the then appear.If the function

is being called, why doesn't it draw on the window? I'm trying to figure out the inner workings of MFC here, it's not a bug or anything.

Comment: I'm guessing here, but it may have to do with the underlying GDI (Graphics Device Interface) of Windows.  In general, to save processing power, it doesn't want to redraw everything every frame like you would in a 3D app, just areas of the screen that have changed.  Something you're doing in MouseMove but not in DrawStroke is probably marking the surface as needing a redraw.

Comment: inner working on windows... not mfc. Have you take into account that the background is erased, before OnPaint is called?

Comment: draw on a memory bitmap in your MouseMove function, disable background painting to avoid flickering, and draw the memory bitmap onto DC when OnPaint is called. To force OnPaint to be called, use InavalidateRect, UpdateWindow...

Comment: I'm doing the tutorial, so ofc I don't know much about how it works, I was hoping someone did it before. Also drawing on a bitmap is not a solution, because I don't want anything to happen differently, I just want to understand why it works this way. I think Nathan's insight may be right, but I don't know much about how the GDIs work.  I know that a device is passed to OnDraw automatically (by whoever calls OnDraw, I don't know which class that is) whereas in the MouseMove function I get it via CClientDC(view). I'm gonna test that next.

Comment: Ok, nevermind, I found out what the problem is. The OnDraw really isn't called except when you put a window over it or make change to the window, like resizing it. I thought it was being called because when I added a breakpoint the VS window would superimpose over the MFC window and when I came back there would be a need to redraw making it call OnDraw again, and there on. When I took the breakpoint off the OnDraw wouldn't be called, thus the confusion. I can see this by setting the two windows without one being over the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When all or part of your windows is out-of-date (called "invalid"), then the message loop will end up getting two messages:  WM_ERASEBKGND and then WM_PAINT.  The typical way for a Windows application to draw is to draw everything in the WM_ERASEBKGND and WM_PAINT handlers.  (I'm not an MFC expert, but I believe WM_PAINT corresponds to OnDraw in MFC.)

So the normal way to handle this would be for the mouse move handler to record the stroke (as it does) and then mark the window as invalid.  This would eventually cause the line to be draw.  However, there could be a slight delay, and it could cause flicker.  The delay is probably insignificant on a modern computer (but Scribble is old).  There are various ways to deal with the flicker.

The Scribble author appears to have chosen to handle the delay and the flicker by drawing the line directly in the mouse move handler instead of invalidating the window and letting the OnDraw do it later.

The invalidation is the key.  You removed the drawing from OnMouseMove, so the line won't get drawn there.  But there's nothing to tell Windows that the window contents are now out of date (invalid), and thus it doesn't get a WM_PAINT message, and the OnDraw doesn't get called.  (Later, when you do something like resize or maximize the window, that *does* invalidate it, and the OnDraw is called and the line suddenly appears.)

If you want to remove the drawing from OnMouseMove, you'll have to replace it with an InvalidateRect call.  That will tell Windows that the window needs to be redrawn.